# I can't bind keys in ZSH / Where can I get escape sequence for the key in SHELL?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, mate-terminal

I try to bind <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> keys in ZSH, but it seems

1. the escape sequences are wrong or
2. terminal (but all of them? mate xterm, st) is blocking these `\E` sequences.

I can bind for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, but I don't know how to bind <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>.

I've tested following escape sequences:

```
"left"  "\eOD"
"right" "\eOC"  
"shome" "\E[1;2~"
"send"  "\E[4;2~"
```

Is there any command "write `\e` sequence for the key `$key`"? Thanks.